# Calling R from Stata

Tags: r, shell, stata

For some very annoying reason, I will not be able to call my R-scripts directly at a data center. I am only allowed to call `stata`, and then `stata` will have to call my R scripts.

For now, I was trying to use the `shell` command:

```
capture cd C:\\Correct\Dir 
shell “C:\\Program Files\R-3.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "myFile.R"
```

The paths are correct, but I only get a blue screen when running this in Stata, and nothing else happens. There is a message in the blue screen, but it disappears immediately, so I have no clue what it says.

How can I proceed debugging this? Is there a better way doing this? I'd prefer not using additional packages like `rsource`, as they need to be certified before installed in the data center and that is a lengthy process.

Comment: Just noticed that you have double backslashes after drive letter, but not for other folders. Does it make a difference if you do `capture cd C:\\Correct\\Dir`

Comment: @user2633645 I'll check that next time I'm in the data center.

Answer (score 2):

I think the presence of the double backslash is causing the problem. The following works for me:

stata

```
cd "path\of\choice"
shell "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "test.R"
```

test.r

```
setwd("path\\of\\choice")
data(mtcars)
mtcars
write.csv(mtcars, "cars.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one example (non-reproducible) of Stata calling R.

```
*----- CALL R -----

// location of input/output files for R
local dirq "`pdir'/proc_data/q_irepriv.csv" // input 1 -> arg1
local dirh "`pdir'/proc_data/h_nophincome.csv" // input 2 -> arg2
local dirRdta "`pdir'/proc_data/`dofile'.Rdta" // output -> arg3
local dirout "`pdir'/" // project_dir -> arg4
local dirout "`dofile'/" // do_file_stub -> arg5

// call -rsource- passing the locations as arguments
rsource using "`pdir'/r_files/`dofile'.R", ///
    roptions(`" --vanilla --args "`dirq'" "`dirh'" "`dirRdta'" "`pdir'" "`dofile'" "')

*----- END OF R -----
```

I use `rsource`, a user-written command which you can download with `ssc install rsource`.

On another note, Stata favors the use of forward slashes in these cases. See [Stata tip 65: Beware the backstabbing backslash](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0042), by Nick Cox.

### Edit

You report a blue screen that disappears, with nothing else happening. This can be the result of R choking on some error within your R script. As an example:

The `.r` script contains:

```
# output OK
head(mtcars)

# provoke error
2+*2
```

and your Stata do-file contains:

```
shell "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.3/bin/x64/Rscript.exe" --no-save --no-restore --verbose "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/rcars.r"
```

The above reproduces your report.

To debug, you can redirect output and error messages using OS shell commands. Instead of the latter, try:

```
shell "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.3/bin/x64/Rscript.exe" --no-save --no-restore --verbose "D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/rcars.r" > Routput.txt 2> Rerror.txt
```

This produces two files:

**Routput.txt** contains

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

and **Rerror.txt** contains

```
running
  'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.3\bin\x64\Rterm.exe --slave --no-restore --no-save --no-restore --file=D:/Datos/rferrer/Desktop/rcars.r'

Error: inesperado '*' in "2+*"
Ejecución interrumpida
```

(The error is in Spanish, but that of course, is irrelevant.)

That is on Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: Regarding your note, I quote from that article: "In fact, you can mix forward and backward slashes willy-nilly in directory or filenames within Stata for Windows, so long as you do not use a backslash just before a left quotation mark."

Comment: True. The wording may not covey the original intention but it was meant primarily as a recommendation. 
I never claimed it was the source of your problem. I too quote from that article:
"The tidiest solution is to use forward slashes consistently ..."
It's less confusing and makes your code portable across operating systems (potentially, at least).
You may consider it a matter of taste and you can act upon that, but
I still stand by the recommendation.

Comment: Wish I could turn my errors to Spanish too - they sound much cooler! ;)